# Find the smallest integer multiple of a Decimal

Tags: code-golf, math, rational-numbers

### The Challenge

Given a [rational number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number), determine the smallest number which is a positive integer multiple of it. Eg.

```
Given: 1.25
   x1: 1.25
   x2: 2.5
   x3: 3.75
   x4: 5
 Thus: Answer is 5
```

### Clarifications

Inputs will be a rational number in the range of `(0,100]` of which the Decimal Representation has no more than 4 digits after the point.

Output must be an integer that is the total after multiplication (`5` in the example, rather than `4`).

I/O may be in any [Standard Format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods), including as a Fraction type.

Be careful if using repeated addition with floats, as `0.3 + 0.3...` results in `2.9999...`.

### Test Cases

```
1.25   -> 5
4.0    -> 4
0.3    -> 3
4.625  -> 37
3.1428 -> 7857
```

### Rules

- [Standard Loopholes Apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so fewest bytes wins!
- Have Fun!

Comment: Surely a fraction type trivialises the question?

Comment: @Neil If you've got a trivial solution, I implore you to submit it. Also worth noting many, even modern languages, don't have fractional types.

Comment: Essentially, this is just finding the numerator of the fraction form of a decimal

Comment: "determine the smallest number which is a positive integer multiple of it." -> "determine the smallest positive integer which is a positive integer multiple of it."? To me the first sounds like we can just output `1*input`.

Comment: Can you clarify whether inaccuracies due to floating-point calculations are disallowed?  This is implied by the "be careful..." sentence, but several answers (including one of mine, as well as O5AB1E, JavaScript, Julia, Pyth, Rust, and Awk) currently fail for input of ```3.1428``` (correct answer ```7857```)...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Inaccuracies due to floating-point errors are disallowed. Answers that fail on this point should clarify explicitly, and attempt to provide an answer that does not. I'll add this as a test case.

Comment: So you're disallowing floating point inputs now? (`3.1428 * 2500 != 7857` with floats [TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v6AoM69Ew1jP0MTIQsvI1MBA8/9/AA).)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Nothing has changed since the original spec. The inaccuracies of floating point math was warned about. You may need to round the result of your multiplication to account for error.

Answer (score 6):

## [Vyxal 2.4.1](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
ƒh
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C6%92h&inputs=0.3&header=&footer=)

A version downgrade improves my byte count somehow.

Well not somehow. 2.4.1 and earlier versions didn't use exact numbers/rationals under the hood, so there was still a "convert decimal to numerator and denominator" built-in (because I've always wanted some form of rationals).

This is a back port of the Factor answer which half ported my original answer.

Takes input as floats because, well, only float input was supported in 2.4.1.

Converts to numerator, denominator. Then gets the first item of that.

### [Vyxal >=2.6](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 35 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 4.375 bytes

```
S\//h
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJBPSIsIiIsIlNcXC8vaCIsIiIsIjEuMjVcbjAuMzMzMzMzMzMzM1xuMC4zXG40XG40LjYyNSJd)

Maths? No thank you!

Takes input as either a fraction object or a float. Both are interpreted as rational implicitly so it doesn't really matter.

Simply casts input to string (which'll be a fraction because vyxal 2 be like that), split on `/` and get the first item.

Comment: Oh! Smart approach!

Comment: Funny thing is that I noticed the pattern after having written a math inspired answer and running test cases :p

Answer (score 5):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 4 bytes

```
1&*.
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8EuJT0FdYU0BVsrBXUdBQMFKyDW1VNwDvJxW1pakqZrscRQTUsPwrzpq8mVmpyRD1RuqGdkCmOb6BkYGMA4BnrGCHEzhCKgBmMTFI4hxNAFCyA0AA)

LCM with 1 to get the numerator of a fractional value.

J has a built-in to extract the numerator/denominator from a number too, but is longer to get just the numerator:

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 6 bytes

```
0{2&x:
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8EuJT0FdYU0BVsrBXUdBQMFKyDW1VNwDvJxW1pakqZrscyg2kitwgrCuemryZWanJEP1GCoZ2QKY5voGRgYwDgGesYIcTOEIqAGYxMUjiHE0AULIDQA)

Comment: TIL about dyadic x:

Answer (score 5):

## Excel, 37 bytes

```
=0+TEXTBEFORE(TEXT(A1,"0/00000"),"/")
```

Input in cell `A1`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 9 bytes

```
numerator
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70sLTG5JL9owU2F0GBPP3crhdzEkgyFgqLUkpLKgqLMvBIFay4uE21TfYulpSVpuhYr80pzU4sSgVog_IV6EHrBAggNAA)

Same idea as lyxal's [Vyxal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265234/97916), just no need for string manipulation.

Less "cheaty," perhaps? This version takes floats as input instead of ratios:

---

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org) + `math.floating-point`, 26 bytes

```
[ double>ratio numerator ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70sLTG5JL9owU3r0GBPP3crhezUorzUHIXcxJIMhYKi1JKSyoKizLwSsIBeWk5-YklmXrpuQT5IzJqLy0TPzMh0aWlJmq7FrmiFlPzSpJxUuyKgonyFvNLcVCArv0ghFqJgWXJiTo6CHoSzYAGEBgA)

And my original answer for posterity:

---

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 34 bytes

```
[ 0 [ 1 + 2dup * ratio? ] loop * ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70sLTG5JL9owc2g0GBPP3crhdzEkgyF7NSivNQcheLUwtLUvOTUYoWCotSSksqCosy8EgVrLq5qLgUgMNQ21DcBsyCksb6hAYSrbapvwVW7tLQkTdfiplK0goFCtIKhgraCUUppgYKWQlFiSWa-vUKsQk5-PogfC1G5NDexQEEPwl6wAEIDAA)

- `0` push zero — this is our multiplier
- `[ ... ratio? ] loop` do `...` while top of stack is a ratio (a number like 5/5 promotes itself to integer automatically)
- `1 +` increment the multiplier
- `2dup *` multiply but keep the input and multiplier on the stack too
- `*` at this point, the input and correct multiplier are on the stack so multiply them

Comment: I managed to backport your answer by downgrading my vyxal version :p

Answer (score 4):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), 11 bytes

```
~x=lcm(x,1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBgqWlJWm6FqvrKmxzknM1KnQMNSEiN6uUFVwrEnMLclK5HIoz8ssV6jTM9fVNDTS5uJQVQlKLS4q5HBKLi1OLSoAypvr6JpoKtrYKpkiCJvr6hmBBEyRBY6CgAVhUwRhZGGi2BVTYHOICmNsA)

Takes [rational number](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/complex-and-rational-numbers/#Rational-Numbers) inputs. Julia also has the function `rationalize` for converting floating point values.

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 33 bytes

```julia
>(x,i=1)=isinteger(i*x)?i*x:x>i+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@//fTqNCJ9PWUNM2szgzryQ1PbVII1OrQtMeSFhV2GVqG/5XVnCtSMwtyEnlcijOyC9XsNMw0DM00eTiUlYISS0uKeZySCwuTi0qAUoY6hmZGmgq2NoqmCKJmugZGEBETZBEDfSMoaIKxiiKzYxMocLm/wE)

Recursive approach which takes an iterator as its own optional argument. The `>` operator is overloaded, since it has lower precedence than `+`, which saves a set of parentheses. Spaces are required around ternary operators beginning in Julia 1.0.The function `isinteger` is a good fit; `last("$(i*x)")<'1'` would be another (longer) approach.

Comment: Another fun one: [`>(x,i=1)=try Int(i*x)catch;x>i+1end`](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@//fTqNCJ9PWUNO2pKhSwTOvRCNTq0IzObEkOcO6wi5T2zA1L@W/soJrRWJuQU4ql0NxRn65gp2GgZ6hiSYXl7JCSGpxSTGXQ2JxcWpRCVDCUM/I1EBTwdZWwRRJ1ETPwAAiaoIkaqBnDBVVMEZRbGZkChU2/w8A)

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>39</s> 31 bytes

```r
\(x,y=x*1:1e6)y[!(y+1e7)%%1][1]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGqvNLc1KLEkvwi26WlJWm6FvtjNCp0Km0rtAytDFPNNCujFTUqtQ1TzTVVVQ1jow1jIapuKsL1aRjqGZlqciH4xnqGJkYWmhCFCxZAaAA)

Correctly handles difficult inputs that otherwise suffer from floating-point inaccuracies.

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 25 bytes (non-competing)

```r
\(x,y=x*1:1e6)y[!y%%1][1]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGqvNLc1KLEkvwi26WlJWm6FjtjNCp0Km0rtAytDFPNNCujFStVVQ1jow1jIfLr4Ro0DPWMTDUhogsWQGgA)

Original answer: fails due to floating-point inaccuracies for `3.1428`, and probably other difficult inputs.

Answer (score 3):

## Google Sheets, 31 bytes

`=+split(text(A1,"#/#####"),"/")`

Put the input in cell `A1` and the formula in `B1`.

Uses number formatting like the [Excel answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265241/119296) to get a fraction, then takes advantage of an undocumented feature of the unary plus operator `+`, i.e., [`uplus()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093608), to get the numerator.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 26 bytes

```ruby
->d{(1..).find{_1/d%1==0}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGiNNulpSVpuha7dO1SqjUM9fQ09dIy81Kq4w31U1QNbW0NamshCm5qFyikRRvqGZkaxHKBmCZ6BgZQpoGesQFc1MzINBaiZcECCA0A)

### Original: [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 31 bytes

```ruby
f=->d,x=1{d*x%1>0?f[d,x+1]:d*x}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboW-9Nsde1SdCpsDatTtCpUDe0M7NOigXxtw1groEAtRNVN7QKFtGhDPSNTg1guENNEz8AAyjTQMzaAi5oZmcZCtMAsAAA)

The more obvious `f=->d{d.to_r.numerator}` does not seem to work for 0.300.

Thanks Value Ink for the tips, but I think that it should be a separate answer.

Comment: `->d{d.to_s.to_r.numerator}` does work and is shorter by 5 bytes, and taking input as a string will lead to the obvious solution you posited. In fact, since the rules explicitly say a fractional input is allowed, `proc &:numerator` also works for the truly "cheaty" version.

Answer (score 2):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 25 bytes

```
n->numerator(bestappr(n))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWO_N07fJKc1OLEkvyizSSUotLEgsKijTyNDUh8jftgPycSo08BV07hYKizLwSIFMJxFFSSAMp01GINtQzMjXQUTDRMzAAUgZ6xgZgnpmRaSzUlAULIDQA)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 53 bytes

Trivial solution (thanks to lyxal for the comment).

```py
lambda n:Fraction(n).numerator
from fractions import*
```

Originally (65 bytes, returns a `float` which can be converted to an `int` while being the same value):

```py
def x(n,i=1):
 while not str(i*n).endswith('.0'):i+=1
 return i*n
```

20 bytes from SuperStormer:

```py
lambda n:n.numerator
```

Comment: 20 bytes: `lambda n:n.numerator` [meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10085)

Comment: The number is not explicitly passed as a Fraction (I assume it is an `int`), however, I guess I'll add that as an extra answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 26 bytes

```perl
($\=$_*++$i)=~/\./&&redo}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19DJcZWJV5LW1slU9O2Tj9GT19NrSg1Jb@2@v9/Qz0jUwMFXTsF03/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/), 17 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBCoAgEAC/snhyYRMz65DUR8TDRgRBKxEF/d7yNAPDCL@7cCmbzjhO@RF98f07liB86oNlWVnHnAjOa89/IlDQzKAI6oNIEFvjegJvrLUE1nQV3gyuTxjKBw)

```
f(n):=num(rat(n))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org), 20 bytes

```python
lambda n:n.numerator
```

An unnamed function that accepts a `Fraction` object and returns the integer.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RczBCsIwEATQe79iySkBCbG1Ygr12K/wErXBgNmE7fYgpd9eW6g4p8cMTP7wK2F1ybT49ra8Xbw/HWCDGsfYk@O0DpQieHIPDgkHCDEnYuj2AtwAXVH4RMD9wBAQZCfFUZe1EeoAq0/amJ@Nrsy/P5f1bmu1tVYo1RSwJlNAll5M2@cM7RUmLzerWajlCw)**

Comment: Floating point inaccuracy I think - it accepts a float and does not perform repeated addition.

Comment: @NickKennedy removed.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 3 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
∧∘1
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=e9Sx/FHHDEMA&f=S1Mw1DMyNeBKUzDRMzAA0QZ6xgYQvpmRKQA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

LCM between input and 1. This is actually really similar to a problem in the APL Competition, [1:7 Let's Be Rational](https://www.dyalogaplcompetition.com/?goto=P17).

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 6 bytes

```
*fsI*Q
```

Takes input as a float.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xyut2FMr8P9/Ez0zI1MA)

```
*fsI*Q
 f        Find the first integer, starting at 1 and counting upward, such that
    *Q    The integer multiplied by the input
   I      Is unchanged when
  s       Cast to an integer
*         Multiply the result (the denominator) by the input
```

---

Same length:

```
fsIcTQ
```

Finds the numerator directly using division.

Comment: Fails for 3.1428

Comment: @NickKennedy My other answer, `fsIcTQ`, works for that input - do you know if it also has a counterexample?

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <s>39</s> 38 bytes

-1 thanks to @corvus_192

```rust
|mut x|{let n=x;while x%1.>0.{x+=n};x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctBCoAgEAXQfaf4BYFSSAWtxO7SokiwIdJowDy71fIt3nn5kFfCPlsSErEA3BLgTX72K4Cf@JMM63uzbgHXvZo6FbkxlDSnDOjvHKel4KgUVUxVCy96NYxS6iLlFw)

Closure naively loops and increments `x` by its intial value until it becomes a whole number.

Comment: I think using `>` instead of `!=` works.

Comment: @corvus_192 you're right, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <s>35</s> 24 bytes

```
{while($1*++a%1);$1*=a}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/ujwjMydVQ8VQS1s7UdVQ0xrIsk2sNfz/31DPyBQA)

(Several improvements by @Dominic van Essen to my original answer: -11 bytes)

---

### Original answer: [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 35 bytes

```
{while($1*++a>int($1*a));print$1*a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/ujwjMydVQ8VQS1s70S4zrwTETNTUtC4oAnJA7Nr//w31jEwB)

Comment: [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/ujwjMydVQ8VQS1s7UdVQ0xrIsk2sNfz/31DPyBQA)...

Comment: Fails for 3.1428

Answer (score 2):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 1 byte

```
ṇ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHHBgqWlJWm6Fosf7mxfUpyUXAzlL1hqYqJvaALhAAA)

`ṇ` = 'numerator' = 'Get the numerator of a number'

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 39 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 4.875 bytes

```
{D⌊≠|+
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJBPSIsIiIsIntE4oyK4omgfCsiLCIiLCIxLjI1XG4wLjNcbjAuMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzNcbjQuNjI1XG40Il0=)

Posting as a separate answer because it doesn't use any fraction string cheese :p

Takes input as either a fraction or a float, as both are implicitly converted to rationals.

### Explained

```
{D⌊≠|+­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
{   |   # ‎⁡While
  ⌊≠    # ‎⁢  The floor of the top of the stack doesn't equal the top of the stack
 D      # ‎⁣  (triplicate before the check so there's a copy left over)
     +  # ‎⁤Add the input to the top of the stack
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>95</s> 71 bytes

```
\.(\d+)$
$1,$.1*0
.*5,0
$.(*2*),0
.*[2468],0
$.(*5*),0
}`0,0
,
^0+|,0*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYg7CoAwEAX7PUeEuC7LSzTBG3gIPyhoYWMhlnr2@MFmmJl9OdZtcimzthlTp7abi9yQcWLUMUg5CMioZc@5vN36Ktb9P8M3rxEPhQYUp4ApJac@gCoFQNASr0cfbg) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
\.(\d+)$
$1,$.1*0
```

On the first pass, delete the decimal point but keep track of how many digits there were after it. (It's golfier to repeat this stage but it has no effect on subsequent passes.)

```
(.*5),0
$.(*2*),0
```

Try doubling the number to create a trailing zero to match.

```
(.*[2468]),0
$.(*5*),0
```

Try multiplying the number by `5` to create a trailing zero to match.

```
0,0
,
```

Remove a pair of matching zeros.

```
}`
```

Repeat until there are no more trailing zeros to remove or the number ends in `1`, `3`, `7` or `9`.

```
^0+|,0*
```

Delete any leading zeros and any remaining working digits.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 27 bytes

```
≔Ｉ⁻θ.ηＦ⊟⪪θ.Ｆ25Ｆ¬﹪ηＩκ≧÷ＩκηＩη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BDoIwEETvfkXT026CHIh44WTk4gFD9AsaULqx6da28PtVqeE2ybzMm0ErP7AyKZ1CoMnCWYUIHdk5wLsQspSIhdDY7J7sBfTs4O4Mxa1EsRayquU/Xvk7wONsGHQh1r0X/sBOuSy50aQjXGxsaaHxsUFZ1HuyMf/QiE1Kh/JY1Wm/mA8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔Ｉ⁻θ.η
```

Remove the decimal point from the input and cast it to integer.

```
Ｆ⊟⪪θ.
```

Loop over each decimal place.

```
Ｆ25Ｆ¬﹪ηＩκ≧÷Ｉκη
```

Divide the integer by 2 and/or 5 if possible.

```
Ｉη
```

Output the resulting integer.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
∞.ΔI/DïQ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Ucc8vXNTPPVdDq8P/P/fWM/QxMgCAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeWhlf8fdczTOzfl0Dp9l8PrA//X6vyPNtQzMtUx0TPQMdAzBtJmQJ6xnqGJkUUsAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
∞         # Push an infinite positive list: [1,2,3,...]
 .Δ       # Pop and find the first integer that's truthy for:
   I/     #  Divide the current integer by the input-decimal
     D    #  Duplicate the decimal
      ï   #  Cast/floor its copy to an integer
       Q  #  Check if both are the same value
          # (after which the found integer is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: @NickKennedy Should be fixed, although it's plausible another test case might still fail due to floating point accuracy tbh.

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 51 bytes

```sql
DECLARE @2 real=4.625

DECLARE @ REAL=@2
WHILE @>floor(@)SET @+=@2
PRINT @
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 2.2, floating-point, 65 bytes

```swift
func f(x:Float,y:Float=1)->Float{return x*y%1==0 ?x*y:f(x,y:y+1)}
```

Back in Swift 2, `%` was supported for floating-point types. I also can't figure out what `Decimal` was called back then.

[Try it on SwiftFiddle!](https://swiftfiddle.com/jpmazbi6ubb2to7lqs2z7vkocm)

### Swift 5.8 + Foundation, decimal, 109 bytes

```swift
func f(x:Decimal,y:Decimal=1)->Decimal{var z=x,w=x*y
NSDecimalRound(&z,&w,0,.up)
return w==z ?w:f(x:x,y:y+1)}
```

Rounding mode doesn't matter; I chose `.up` because it's the shortest. The function signature of `NSDecimalRound` makes more sense in Objective-C where you only work with `NSDecimal*` and not the struct directly.

[Try it on SwiftFiddle!](https://swiftfiddle.com/7dkq6avb3vb4ldkwm36kid7khu)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 31 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,m=n)=>(m+1e9)%1?f(n,m+n):m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/P81WI08n1zZP09ZOI1fbMNVSU9XQPg0kpp2naZX7v6AoM69EI4HLUM/I1EBB105BpTpNA8zRrOUy0TMwgAuCOUBBAz1jhCCYA1ZpZmSKUAnkAAWN9IwVFGCCQA5QKEHzPwA)

Take float

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 4 bytes

```javascript
x=>x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvu/wtau4n9BUWZeiUYCl6m@iYKunYJKdZqGqY6JZi2Xib4hTMBExxAoYKxvaAATMdYxNAAJmetbwIXMdSyAQkZgZQowUSOoygTN/wA)

Comment: Is the 4-byte answer a joke?  It obviously fails if input is given as a non-reduced fraction.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I'd say requiring reduced fraction input is usually reasonable, but yeah it's not serious here

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 16 bytes

Builtin solution posted as a separate answer from [G B's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265250/52194) per their suggestion. Takes a `Rational` as input.

```ruby
proc &:numerator
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGiNNulpSVpuhYbCorykxXUrPJKc1OLEkvyiyDCNx3LMzJzUhXSU0uKuRQSdZIUbBVU4vWKC3IySzT0FbR17RT0NbkUChSKbNOiE_VK8uOLYnWAHNskEDuTKzUvBWLQgpv2hnpGpgoKCkAtplwmegYKELYJl4GeMZRtDBQ3AykCsc25jPUMTYwsQBxzC1NziDkA)

### [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-n`, 18 bytes

The same idea but takes input from STDIN via `-n` and prints the answer.

```ruby
p$_.to_r.numerator
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpclm0km6eUuyCpaUlaboWmwpU4vVK8uOL9PJKc1OLEkvyiyASUPkFOw31jEy5TPQMuAz0jIG0GZBnrGdoYmQBUQAA)